How to deliver static frontend via CDN (https) to customer for an on-prem client (http)
Our customers have specific backend programs running on their local machines with no access to the internet, we want to deliver a UI to them to help visualizing their backend(s). The customers themselves can obviously connect to the backend.
We thought that delivering the frontend/UI via Cloudfare R2 as a local-first static website would be perfect for this, but as it turns out to this backend engineer (me), browsers don't really like https websites to connect to http endpoints.
How would you design a solution to this problem?
Solutions that wont work unfortunately:

Using a different protocol --> we have no access to the backend software
Relaxing the browser settings (even just for the frontend) --> customers are in an industry where this is impossible
Self-signed certificates for their backend with sth like mkcert --> too much hassle for customer

Solutions that could work, but I'm not sure how elegant they are:

Setting up the customer with some kind of reverse proxy for their backend
Scrapping the idea and delivering the frontend as a Docker image running some kind of lightweight http server

Am I trying to fix a broken idea?

You are running face-first into the Same Origin Policy in web browsers. This is something that Cross-Origin Resource Sharing attempts to solve, but lays down its own constraints.
You simply need a real web server.
Or...
Run the frontend from their computer using a lightweight web server. Forget the CDN. Do all of this locally, however this has me concerned:

Relaxing the browser settings (even just for the frontend) --> customers are in an industry where this is impossible

If security is a concern, then you need to implement things properly, which means using a real web server, with real HTTPS. Self-signed certificates shouldn't be a problem if your organization has its own Certificate Authority. This CA doesn't need to be public. It could be hidden behind a firewall. Given the sensitive nature of your industry, people should be connected to some internal network or VPN anyhow.

Setting up the customer with some kind of reverse proxy for their backend

Sure, this could work, but it could be a monster pain for the people maintaining these IT systems, especially when alternatives exist that don't require reverse proxies.

Scrapping the idea and delivering the frontend as a Docker image running some kind of lightweight http server

Most "lightweight" HTTP servers come with a warning out of the box saying that it isn't suitable for production. Here again, security is what I'm thinking about. Web servers aren't magic. They can have vulnerabilities in them, and then you need to patch those flaws. The saving grace here is those machines do not have access to the Internet. Presumably, firewall rules prevent them from making outbound HTTP calls.
My instinct tells me that if these machines are properly isolated from the Internet and the rest of your organization's internal network then running a lightweight HTTP server would be less of a risk than hacking your way around SSL, and the same origin policy in web browsers.
We tend to build web applications for everything. It's a knee-jerk reaction, and the tools for building web applications are pretty mature and flexible. As an alternative, I'm wondering if you should be building a traditional native GUI application instead, especially if these machines don't need to talk to one another.

I fully agree with you that utilizing our customers local CA would be the best way to go (in future). Right now this is unfortunately not possible. I have question regarding the difference between "delivering a docker image with a lightweight http server" (my suggestion) and "running a local web server on their machines" (your suggestion). Was I not clear that I meant that we deliver them a docker image to run and serve the frontend locally on their machines, or is there something else that is different? Thank you very much for the detailed reply

My answer was a bit rambling, but I assumed "docker image with a lightweight http server" meant "run the server locally."

Sorry, I'm lost right now. So, given the constraints, would delivering a docker image to our customers with a lightweight web server, serving our frontend locally on their machines suffice your suggestion of  "Run the frontend from their computer using a lightweight web server"?. Or am I misinterpreting your suggestion?

It would suffice. Docker is just the delivery mechanism.

"you should be building a traditional native GUI application" theres prob a way to wrap a js framework front end in a windows app these days
